Why am I getting this error in Jest with NestJS?
I'm writing some unit tests in NestJS using Jest, I'm testing a repository class which looks like this:
// imports...


@Injectable()
export class BiometricDataTempRepository extends Repository<BiometricDataTemp> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(BiometricDataTemp)
        private readonly biometricDataTempRepository: Repository<BiometricDataTemp>,
    ) {
        super(biometricDataTempRepository.target, biometricDataTempRepository.manager, biometricDataTempRepository.queryRunner);
    }

    async store(biometricFlow: CreateBiometricDataTempDtoRepo): Promise<BiometricDataTemp> {
        try {
            const biometricStatus = this.create({
                ...biometricFlow,
                biometricFlow: { id: biometricFlow.biometricFlowId },
                status: { id: 1 },
            });
            return await this.biometricDataTempRepository.save(biometricStatus);
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }

    async updateBiometricFlowId(dto: { documentId: string; biometric_flow_id: number }): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.biometricDataTempRepository.update({ documentId: dto.documentId }, { biometricFlow: { id: dto.biometric_flow_id } });
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
}

and this is what I've written in the spec file:
// imports...

describe('BiometricDataTempRepository', () => {
  let repository: BiometricDataTempRepository;
  let biometricDataTempRepository: Repository<BiometricDataTemp>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        BiometricDataTempRepository,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(BiometricDataTemp),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    repository = module.get<BiometricDataTempRepository>(BiometricDataTempRepository);
    biometricDataTempRepository = module.get<Repository<BiometricDataTemp>>(getRepositoryToken(BiometricDataTemp));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(repository).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('store', () => {
    it('should successfully store biometric data', async () => {
      const biometricFlow: CreateBiometricDataTempDtoRepo = {
        templateRaw: Buffer.from('some-template-raw-data'),
        documentImage: Buffer.from('some-document-image'),
        faceImage: Buffer.from('some-face-image'),
        faceImageAvatar: Buffer.from('some-face-image-avatar'),
        documentId: '123456',
        biometricFlowId: 1,
      };

      const biometricData: BiometricDataTemp = {
        id: 1,
        templateRaw: biometricFlow.templateRaw,
        documentImage: biometricFlow.documentImage,
        faceImage: biometricFlow.faceImage,
        faceImageAvatar: biometricFlow.faceImageAvatar,
        documentId: biometricFlow.documentId,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        status: { id: 1, name: 'Active', biometricData: [], biometricFlows:[], biometricDataTemp: [] } as Status, 

        biometricFlow: { 
          id: biometricFlow.biometricFlowId, 
          token: 'token', 
          clientId: null, 
          operation: { id: 1, name: 'Operation' } as Operation, 
          documentId: null, 
          documentType: null, 
          status: { id: 1, name: 'Active', biometricData: [], biometricFlows:[], biometricDataTemp: [] } as Status, 
          createdAt: new Date(), 
          updatedAt: new Date(), 
          biometricData: [], 
          biometricDataTemp: null 
        } as BiometricFlow,
      };

      jest.spyOn(biometricDataTempRepository, 'create').mockReturnValue(biometricData);
      jest.spyOn(biometricDataTempRepository, 'save').mockResolvedValue(biometricData);

      await expect(repository.store(biometricFlow)).resolves.toEqual(biometricData);
    });

    it('should throw an error if store fails', async () => {
      const biometricFlow: CreateBiometricDataTempDtoRepo = {
        templateRaw: Buffer.from('some-template-raw-data'),
        documentImage: Buffer.from('some-document-image'),
        faceImage: Buffer.from('some-face-image'),
        faceImageAvatar: Buffer.from('some-face-image-avatar'),
        documentId: '123456',
        biometricFlowId: 1,
      };
      const error = new Error('Test error');

      const biometricData: BiometricDataTemp = {
        id: 1,
        templateRaw: biometricFlow.templateRaw,
        documentImage: biometricFlow.documentImage,
        faceImage: biometricFlow.faceImage,
        faceImageAvatar: biometricFlow.faceImageAvatar,
        documentId: biometricFlow.documentId,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        status: { id: 1, name: 'Active', biometricData: [], biometricFlows:[], biometricDataTemp: [] } as Status, 
        biometricFlow: { 
          id: biometricFlow.biometricFlowId, 
          token: 'token', 
          clientId: null, 
          operation: { id: 1, name: 'Operation' } as Operation, 
          documentId: null, 
          documentType: null, 
          status: { id: 1, name: 'Active' } as Status, 
          createdAt: new Date(), 
          updatedAt: new Date(), 
          biometricData: [], 
          biometricDataTemp: null 
        } as BiometricFlow,
      };

      jest.spyOn(biometricDataTempRepository, 'create').mockReturnValue(biometricData);
      jest.spyOn(biometricDataTempRepository, 'save').mockRejectedValue(error);

      await expect(repository.store(biometricFlow)).rejects.toThrow('Test error');
    });
  });

But I am getting this error for the first 2 tests, for store and for error throwing, the update test is passing, what should I modify in order to pass all the test cases successfully?
BiometricDataTempRepository
    ✓ should be defined (7 ms)
    store
      ✕ should successfully store biometric data (4 ms)
      ✕ should throw an error if store fails (15 ms)
    updateBiometricFlowId
      ✓ should successfully update biometric flow id (2 ms)
      ✓ should throw an error if update fails (4 ms)

  ● BiometricDataTempRepository › store › should successfully store biometric data

    expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Received promise rejected instead of resolved
    Rejected to value: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')]

